# Google Sheets IF statement with OR logic error?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, parse-error

The formula I created for a Google Sheet is not working. Seems to be a logic error but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

This formula is being entered into F3:

```
=IF(OR(C3="",D3="",E3=""), "", TODAY())
```

I thought this would do it. If C3 is blank OR D3 is blank OR E3 is blank, then leave the cell blank, else show today's date. It's treating it like an AND statement and only putting today's date if all three cells (C3, D3, E3) have something in them.

Comment: I also tried 

=IF(C3>="", "", TODAY(), IF(D3="", "", TODAY(), IF(E3="", "", TODAY())))

but I get this error
Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 4 arguments.

Answer (score 1):

this pretty much works. perhaps try:

```
=IF(OR(C3=""; D3=""; E3=""); ; TODAY())
```

[image: 0]

perhaps you need `AND`:

```
=IF(AND(C3=""; D3=""; E3=""); ; TODAY())
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Yes, that is the opposite of what I wanted. I needed it to be if just one of three cells had data it would post the date. Here is what I just figured out

=IF(AND(C3="",D3="",E3=""), "", TODAY())

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. My logic was off. I needed an AND not an OR because if any of the cells were = "" the OR was TRUE and therefore "" unless all were filled in

Correct formula:
=IF(AND(C3="",D3="",E3=""), "", TODAY())

Comment: Maybe it's easier to reverse the logic - =if(or(C3<>"",D3<>"",E3<>""),today(),"")